# Java choosing variables in a loop

Tags: java, variables, loops

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to choose between variables in a loop(s). The following code what I have works, but I would like to have a better way to do it if possible.

```
Map<Character, Character> axes = new HashMap<Character, Character>();

(...)

for (int w = 0; w < image.getWidth(); w++) {
    for (int h = 0; h < image.getHeight(); h++) {
        for (int d = 0; d < depth; d++) {
            int x = axes.get('x') == 'w' ? w : (axes.get('x') == 'h' ? h : d);
            int y = axes.get('y') == 'w' ? w : (axes.get('y') == 'h' ? h : d);
            int z = axes.get('z') == 'w' ? w : (axes.get('z') == 'h' ? h : d);

            (...)

        }
    }
}
```

In what I have above I need to assign certain coordinates of an image to a 3D coordinate with depth but the sides it uses change depending on the direction it faces. Is there faster way to execute the code without having to make separate loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
int[] coords = new int[3];
int width = image.getWidth();
int height = image.getHeight();
for (coords[0] = 0; coords[0] < width; ++coords[0])
{
    for (coords[1] = 0; coords[1] < height; ++coords[1])
    {
        for (coords[2] = 0; coords[2] < depth; ++coords[2])
        {
            int x = coords[x_idx];
            int y = coords[y_idx];
            int z = coords[z_idx];
            …
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, I was writing the very same solution here (you just forgot to tell `x_idx = axes.get('x') == 'w' ? 0 : (axes.get('x') == 'h' ? 1 : 2);` before the loops

Comment: Those are plenty additional array accesses, which may actually slow the whole thing down, as index bound checks must be done all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `axes.get(...)` calls out of the loops. It should be fast enough then. If it is still too slow, do also the logic outside the loops and do a switch in the inner loop:

```
final char xaxis = axes.get('x');
final char yaxis = axes.get('y');
final char zaxis = axes.get('z');
final int  mode  = xaxis == 'x' && yaxix == 'y' ? 1 : ....
```

and then

```
           switch (mode) {
             case 1: x = w; y = h; z = d; break;
             case 2: ...
           }
           // work with x,y,z
```